# How to count number of weekends between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

In sqlite I want to get the count of weekends between 2 dates, but without using a table (from).  For example, a query like this:

```
SELECT Count(d) 
WHERE  Strftime('%w', d) <> "0" 
    AND Strftime('%w', d) <> "7" 
    AND d > "2016-03-20 00:00:00.000 +00:00" 
    AND d < "2016-03-25 00:00:00.000 +00:00"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you calculate the number of weeks between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538486/how-do-you-calculate-the-number-of-weeks-between-two-dates)

Comment: @MartinGottweis your duplicate is for ms sql server, while this question is for SQLite.

Comment: i don't want to use dateDiff function , i want to apply a condition which is the day of week != 0 and != 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BETWEEN** operator:

```
WHERE (format,date_column) between date1 AND date2
WHERE ('%Y%m%d',Date) between '20161001' AND '20161005'
```

Convert the date in this format in the column.

Comment: there is no date column , i just have 2 dates and want  to count the weekends between them (no "from" clause)